# Returning non-matches in a CoGroupByKey in Apache Beam?

Tags: apache-beam

In my Beam workflow, I fetch daily data from an API endpoint into my database and while I am doing that, I am joining additional info from a fact table onto the daily data using `CoGroupByKey`.

Now, if the key in my primary table is not matching with the fact table, i.e. I see daily data for a new object, how do I get a list/PCollection of all these non-matching keys so I can fetch the new "facts" for the non-matching keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the out of the `CoGroupByKey` each element is a `CoGbkResult`.

In the `CoGbkResult` for each key there will be an iterable for elements from the primary table and and iterable for elements from the fact table. If the iterable from the fact table is empty, then there were no matches.

You may find that using Beam schemas and the [CoGroup](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.27.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/schemas/transforms/CoGroup.html) transform is even easier.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up adding dummy values (1s) and filtering for values that didn't have a 1 in the fact table.